# mailgun email breaks at ampersand in query string (email body)

Tags: vb.net, mailgun

I'm sending an email using mailgun. Email body is html content which has a URL with query string parameters. In the received email, content has broken at "&" character in query string. I am using vb.net with standard httpwebrequest.

Appreciate any help here.

Here is sample code:

```
Try
        Body = "<br/>Please take a moment to review and sign your payment.</p><p><a href='http://test.com/signme.aspx?ID=xxxxxxxx&ID2=xxxxxx=='>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Click here to review and electronically sign the authorization</a></p>"
        Dim strDataToPost As String = String.Empty
        Dim myWebRequest As HttpWebRequest
        Dim myRequestStream As Stream
        Dim myStreamWriter As StreamWriter

        Dim myWebResponse As HttpWebResponse
        Dim myResponseStream As Stream
        Dim myStreamReader As StreamReader
        myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL)
        ' Set the method to "POST" and the content type so the server knows to expect form data in the body of the request.
        With myWebRequest
            .Method = "POST"
            .ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        End With
        myWebRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("api", "mykey")
        strDataToPost = strDataToPost + "from=" + FromEmail
        strDataToPost = strDataToPost + "&to=" + ToEmail
        If Cc.Trim.Length > 0 Then strDataToPost = strDataToPost + "&cc=" + Cc
        If Bcc.Trim.Length > 0 Then strDataToPost = strDataToPost + "&bcc=" + Bcc
        strDataToPost = strDataToPost + "&subject=" + Subject
        strDataToPost = strDataToPost + "&html=" + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Body)

        ' Get a handle on the Stream of data we're sending to the remote server, connect a StreamWriter to it, 
        ' and write our data to the Stream using the StreamWriter.
        myRequestStream = myWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
        myStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(myRequestStream)
        myStreamWriter.Write(strDataToPost)
        'WriteToLogFile("Data :" & strDataToPost)
        myStreamWriter.Flush()
        myStreamWriter.Close()
        myRequestStream.Close()

        ' Get the response from the remote server.
        myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse()

        ' Get the server's response status?
        ' Just like when we sent the data, we'll get a reference to the response Stream, connect a StreamReader to the Stream and 
        ' use the reader to actually read the reply.
        myResponseStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
        myStreamReader = New StreamReader(myResponseStream)
        Dim strResult As String = myStreamReader.ReadLine()
        myStreamReader.Close()
        myResponseStream.Close()
        myWebResponse.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteToLogFile("Error Occured:" & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Try html encoding your message before posting it.

"&" signals the beginning of a html character

```
(i.e. "&#36;" = "$")
```

So it looks like when the browser sees the "&" it is grabbing the next few characters behind it and trying to translate it into a html character, which will throw an error because "&ID2=x" isn't a valid html character code. To prevent this, try adding this line beneath your Body = "text" line

```
Body = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(Body)
```

That will translate all the html special characters in your body string into their corresponding html codes. If your email is being displayed as html, there should be no more errors. However, if there's a case where the email must be displayed or interpreted by your program as plain text, then you would need to reverse the process using HtmlDecode.

Comment: Hi soohoonigan, thanks for the reply. I tried HTMLEncode, mailgun returning with an error (bad request).